# Best Practices for verifying an App request is valid

Tags: api, facebook-app-requests

I am currently using User to User App requests to have one user invite another user to my application. The first event I receive is from the dialog which lists the request ID and users it was sent to. The second event I receive is when a user follows the app request.

What is the best practice for verifying that the request ID's and users provided by the first event are valid. I cannot read all apprequests sent by the user, and when the user triggers the second event, I cannot call /me/apprequests to verify the ID either.